# AttributeOverride set null value to unmapped field

Tags: java, jpa

I have class

```
@Embeddable
public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
   private String field3;

// getters, setters
}
```

and I have mapped class

```
public class MappedClass implements Serializable
{
   @Embedded
   @AttributeOverrides(
      {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "field1", column = @Column(name = "column1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "field2", column = @Column(name = "column2")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "field3", column = @Column(name = "column3"))
      })
   private MyClass myClassField1;

   @Embedded
   @AttributeOverrides(
      {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "field1", column = @Column(name = "column1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "field2", column = @Column(name = "column2")),
      })
   private MyClass myClassField2;

// setters, getters

}
```

I want that 'filed3' in myClassField2 be 'null', becouse 'field3' hasn't DB mapping.
What can I do? JPA search value for 'field3' in column 'field3'

In Hibernate all passed normal!

```
   <component name="myClassField1" class="MappedClass">
           <property name="field1" type="string" column="column1" />
           <property name="field2" type="string" column="column2" />
           <property name="field3" type="string" column="column3" />
   <component/>  

   <component name="myClassField2" class="MappedClass">
           <property name="field1" type="string" column="column1" />
           <property name="field2" type="string" column="column2" />
   <component/>
```

But I need this in JPA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible. EIther a field is persistent, or it's transient. It can't be sometimes one and sometimes the other.

Consider defining a MyClass1 with just two fields, and a MyClass2 extending MyClass1 and adding the third field. Use the first one for `myClassField2`, and the second one for `myClassField1`.

Note that, in your example, you have mapped column1 and column2 twice, which is also incorrect.